# How to cluster PostgreSQL table using columns/fields from other tables

Tags: postgresql, clustered-index

I'd like to cluster a PostgreSQL table based on information in other tables.

Imagine two tables - `foos (id, baz_id, name)` and `bars (foo_id, name)`. `bars.foo_id` is a foreign key reference to `foos.id`.

I'd like to cluster the bars table so that it is ordered by foos.baz_id.

Is this possible?

Comment: Your sample schema doesn't actually show a relationship between the two tables (I'm guessing there should be a foo_id on foos). More importantly, could you explain why you want to cluster the data in this way / what you hope it will achieve?

Comment: @IMSoP My data is such that it's highly likely that `bars` related to `foos` that have the same `baz_id` will be returned in the same query. None of the other columns on `bars` can simulate that ordering (although `foo_id` isn't horrible). I expect this will decrease IO read time significantly on a several hundred million record table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished using denormalization.

Add a `bars.baz_id` column and add triggers or application layer logic that maintains the appropriate values in that table.

Then add an index that uses the denormalized `bars.baz_id` column and cluster by that index.

```
CREATE INDEX index_bars_on_baz_id ON bars (baz_id);
CLUSTER bars USING index_bars_on_baz_id;
```

Comment: Note that `CLUSTER` in Postgres doesn't create a permanently clustered index like in other DBMSes, it just arranges the data that exists at that time based on the index. New data will still be added wherever it fits, until you run `CLUSTER` again to rearrange it.

Comment: It's also important to re-`ANALYZE` after each re-`CLUSTER`.