# Clustering by first column

Tags: postgresql, cluster-analysis, unique

I have to create a table on PostgreSQL, where it will be clustered by first column. And another table,No clustering,Only one variant column (json like), Unique per second column.

Can anyone help me plz?

Comment: hi, perhaps the `CLUSTER` directive https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085656/how-to-cluster-postgresql-table-using-columns-fields-from-other-tables

Comment: You have to describe what you mean by "clustering".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.